# AS3 stop function then add back to menu button

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello im new in AS3 and i have this simple game project but i cant make back to menu button . can someone help me ?
 the project have 3 frames , frame 1=title frame2= menu , frame 3 = game
and i want to go back to frame 1 when the game hit gameover . 
but when i go back to frame 1 with GotoandStop , it always show error message like :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at next_fla::MainTimeline/BintangGo()[next_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:88]

or is there a way to reset everything and play again at frame 1 ?

this is my code at frame 3

```html
import flash.events.Event;
game_over.visible=false;
men.visible=false;
var scoree:uint;

tong.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,meteorGo)

function meteorGo(ev:Event){
 tong.y+=15
 tong.rotation+=7
 if(tong.y>=810){
  tong.y=0-Math.random()*800
  tong.x=Math.random()*480
 }
 if(tong.hitTestObject(wong)){
  game_over.visible=true;
  men.visible=true;
  wong.x=1600-Math.random()*400
 }
}

import flash.events.Event;

apel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,apelgo)
apel.y=0-Math.random()*800
apel.x=Math.random()*480

function apelgo(ev:Event){
 apel.y+=11
 if(apel.y>=810){
  apel.y=0-Math.random()*800
  apel.x=Math.random()*480
 }
 if(apel.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore5();
  apel.y=0-Math.random()*800
  apel.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}

botol.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,botolgo)
botol.y=0-Math.random()*800
botol.x=Math.random()*480
function botolgo(ev:Event){
 botol.y+=12
 if(botol.y>=810){
  botol.y=0-Math.random()*800
  botol.x=Math.random()*480
 }
 if(botol.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore2();
  botol.y=0-Math.random()*800
  botol.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}

bintang.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGo)
bintang.y=0-Math.random()*800
bintang.x=Math.random()*480

function BintangGo(ev:Event){
 bintang.y+=9
 if(bintang.y>=810){
  bintang.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintang.x=Math.random()*480
  
 }
 if(bintang.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore();
  bintang.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintang.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}


function init():void
{
 scoree = 0;
 scorecounter.text = scoree.toString();

}


function updateScore5():void
{
 scoree += 5;
     scorecounter.text = scoree.toString();
}

function updateScore2():void
{
 scoree += 2;
     scorecounter.text = scoree.toString();
}

function updateScore():void
{
 scoree += 1;
     scorecounter.text = scoree.toString();
}


bintanga.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGoa)
bintanga.y=0-Math.random()*800
bintanga.x=Math.random()*480

function BintangGoa(ev:Event){
 bintanga.y+=9
 if(bintanga.y>=810){
  bintanga.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintanga.x=Math.random()*480
  
 }
 if(bintanga.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore();
  bintanga.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintanga.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}

bintangb.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGob)
bintangb.y=0-Math.random()*800
bintangb.x=Math.random()*480

function BintangGob(ev:Event){
 bintangb.y+=2
 if(bintangb.y>=810){
  bintangb.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintangb.x=Math.random()*480
  
 }
 if(bintangb.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore();
  bintangb.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintangb.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}

bintangc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGoc)
bintangc.y=0-Math.random()*800
bintangc.x=Math.random()*480

function BintangGoc(ev:Event){
 bintangc.y+=9
 if(bintangc.y>=810){
  bintangc.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintangc.x=Math.random()*480
  
 }
 if(bintangc.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore();
  bintangc.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintangc.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}
bintangd.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGod)
bintangd.y=0-Math.random()*800
bintangd.x=Math.random()*480

function BintangGod(ev:Event){
 bintang.y+=9
 if(bintangd.y>=810){
  bintangd.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintangd.x=Math.random()*480
  
 }
 if(bintangd.hitTestObject(wong)){
  updateScore();
  bintangd.y=0-Math.random()*800
  bintangd.x=Math.random()*480
 }
}

mobil.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,MobilGO)
mobil.y=-1600-Math.random()*800
mobil.x=Math.random()*480

function MobilGO(ev:Event){
 mobil.y+=20
 if(mobil.y>=810){
  mobil.y=-1600-Math.random()*800
  mobil.x=Math.random()*480
  
 }
 if(mobil.hitTestObject(wong)){
  game_over.visible=true;
  men.visible=true;
  wong.x=1600-Math.random()*400

 }
}




Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

men.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, m12);

function m12(event:TouchEvent):void
{
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,MobilGO);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,meteorGo);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,apelgo);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,botolgo);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGoa);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGob);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGoc);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGod);
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BintangGo);


 removeChild (tong);
 removeChild (botol);
 removeChild (apel);
 removeChild (bintang);
 removeChild (wong);
 removeChild (bintanga);
 removeChild (bintangb);
 removeChild (bintangc);
 removeChild (bintangd);
 removeChild (mobil);
 gotoAndStop(1);

}

stop();
```

tyvm if u can help me

Answer (score 0):

On *both* frame 1 and frame 2 of your main timeline, try adding `stop();` as the very first thing.

Judging by the error message mentioning "frame 3" I am guessing it is trying to go to frame 3, and so explicitly calling `stop()` as soon as possible might prevent that.

Comment: What line of code is line `88`? I see that you clarified that this code is actually on frame 3. It is possible the object (movie clip) you are trying to reference no longer exists on frame 3, but knowing what actual code statement (on line 88) is throwing the error would be helpful.